# Setting up wordpress on zend server 8.0

Tags: mysql, wordpress, apache, deployment, zend-server

I'm trying to set up a local web server for some test development for the first time.

I have Zend Server 8.0.2 running apache with MYSQL 5 installed. I've already got the app for phpMyAdmin installed successfully but am having trouble deploying the Wordpress app.

When I install I'm getting an error "post_stage.php error: exited with status 1. ."

When setting it up I'm using the parameters which are pretty basic.

- site_url:    http://localhost/wp
- blog_name:   WordPress Demo
- db_host: localhost
- db_username: root
- db_password: *******
- db_name: wordpress
- admin_username:  admin
- admin_password:  *******
- admin_email: admin@localhost.com
- table_prefix:    wp_

I'm not sure but my MYSQL root password is still defaulted to blank but when setting up Wordpress it was asking for an admin password and db_password which I couldn't leave blank so I just put in a password. Does this db_password have to match the MYSQL root password?

I'm not sure why wordpress won't install successfully on the server. This is my first time doing something like this and I am utterly lost. Tried searching around for any documentation but can't seem to figure out why it's doing this or how to change the MYSQL root password on zend server.

Comment: What's your local system setup? Mac, Linux, Windows?  I'm curious because I've used the built-in installer supplied in Zend Server 8 on Mac pretty consistently well, but not other platforms.

Comment: I honestly gave up with Zend. I installed xampp and it worked like a charm. Haven't had any issues at all over the past 6 months.

Comment: Quick Note: Zend works with XAMPP - Zend just replaces the PHP interpreter that apache uses with Zend's' (and also adds 20 or so other features, most awesomely Z-Ray, which is the best way to debug WordPress Performance issues or track down which DB calls are taking up all your I/O): https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QOk_forfcxs

You still need apache & MySQL and an OS with Zend, though it DOES come with an installer that includes all of those, so it can look like XAMPP.

Answer (score 0):

[Daniel Berman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4795098/daniel-berman?tab=profile) has an [pretty straightforward You Tube video on Zend's official YouTube channel](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yJLAWKfR_Xg) on how to complete the install in 7 minutes on AWS.

The key takeaway is that there is an installation option available by accessing the Top Nav Menu > Overview > Guide Page link.  That page provides a set of links allowing you install any of the following with just a few clicks:

- WordPress
- Magento
- Drupal
- phpMyAdmin
- Joomla
- phpBB

You can also [jump straight to the installation goodness @ 5:46](https://youtu.be/yJLAWKfR_Xg?t=5m49s).

Comment: The answer is too big and doesn't bring anything then a link to a video. That video itself might be a good answer to the question, but rules of SO make it clear that if linking an external source, so should summarize at least the most important parts.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate your input! With your rep can you can see the deleted comments & my original answer? I was dv'd earlier because my answer was too SHORT according to his interp of SO rules....  The thing is that It's a one click install.  Any advice on much should that be summarized? Not trying to be snarky, I genuinely thought I was being helpful by going through the other things that Daniel's (official maintainer of the Zend YouTube Training & Instructional Channel) video includes after the 2nd to last word before the bulleted list that says it takes 1 click

Comment: *You can see the deleted comments* No, only diamond moderators and SE employees can see deleted comments. Sorry about the strange interaction on your answer. There were occasions where an answerer presented a link-only answer to a video that supposedly fixed the issue. After looking at the video it turned out that it didn't answer the question at all either because it was something completely different (&spam) or made a different point about the same technology. It was a waste of time for me to watch the video which is why I don't do that anymore. Answers should be self-contained.

Comment: I guess your point is that the installation takes only one click and there is no need to worry about settings things up (now). This is a valid answer, but I think it doesn't really engage the OP, but that might also not be necessary, because the question is rather old.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: I think i've managed to capture the core components of the process now, would you agree?

Comment: Added.  @inmyth would you mind reviewing the video & my answer to help me confirm I've captured the core of the answer?  There's been a lot of back and forth on this and based on the WP stack exchange beta site there's a good bit of interest in this topic.  I want to make sure i'm doing my best to help my fellow members and would value your input.